# CS0266 C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Object' to ''. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#

I have a compiler error where the compiler cannot convert type "UnityEngine.Object to Gun. I don't think that these are different file types, but anyway, here's my code. I've been stumped on this and I'm no pro on C# yet, so forgive me if it's a n00b mistake. Idk how to use the code insert on this, it confuses me, so here's a printscreen.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GunController : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform WeaponHold;
    public Gun startingGun;
    Gun equippedGun;

    void Start()
    {
        if (startingGun != null)
        {
            EquipGun(startingGun);
        }
    }

    public void EquipGun(Gun gunToEquip)
    {
        if(equippedGun != null)
        {
            Destroy(equippedGun.gameObject);
        }
        equippedGun = Instantiate(gunToEquip, WeaponHold.position,WeaponHold.rotation);
        equippedGun.transform.parent = WeaponHold;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code directly in your question, not a screenshot.

Comment: `"Idk how to use the code insert on this, it confuses me"` -- It's copy & paste. No special "secrets".

Comment: It didn't really work for me when I tried it first time, but now it does. Of course.

Comment: With the instantiate code, I tried both equippedGun = Instantiate(gunToEquip, WeaponHold.position,WeaponHold.rotation)as GameObject; and equippedGun = (GameObject)Instantiate(gunToEquip, WeaponHold.position,WeaponHold.rotation); and also replaced GameObject with Gun, no luck.

Comment: Instantiate is returning UnityEngine.Object and your are trying to assign it to Gun. What you can do is to cast or create new instance of gun and assign parameters from object to gun one by one. Or use constructor. Or define implicit cast.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Instantiate`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) method returns an `object`, which you can cast to the necessary type.

Cast it to a `Gun` and it should stop complaining:

```
equippedGun = (Gun)Instantiate(gunToEquip, WeaponHold.position, WeaponHold.rotation);
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but I still getting an error in the compiler... but when I load it into Unity it works... weird. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your class inherits from MonoBehaviour.

```
public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour{

}
```